# How to Recover Data from RAID1 or RAID0 (QNAP TS-219P+)?

Tags: windows, linux, server, data-recovery

QNAP TS-219P+ supports two RAID types, RAID1 and RAID0, as well as JBOD, which is sometimes referred to as linear RAID, but technically it isn’t a RAID at all. In the end, redundancy in this NAS is only achieved by using a mirrored RAID. But if one of the disks fails in either RAID0 or JBOD, a part of the information is bound to be lost.

I have asituation when the NAS is broken; all the files are still on its disks but it’s impossible to retrieve them unless use a specialized software tool.

The matter is that a NAS storage device uses its own operating system which builds the RAID in a certain way and then writes data to its disks. Even when the hard disks are connected to another storage device or computer, their condition cannot be restored.

For example, when the disks are connected to a Windows computer, I see some partitions with an unrecognized file system; another possible case is that the operating system will suggest initializing them in the Disk Management app – which is going to erase all the data still remaining on the disks.

In a Linux operating system, the disk partitions will be displayed as Linux RAID, and the option to mount is unavailable.

So, to retrieve the information from the hard disks, I need a special tool to rebuild the RAID system and restore access to the files which are stored inside the disk array.

Yes, there are various programs for data recovery from RAID arrays. But I need feedback from those who have experience using such tools. Recommend programs that you have had experience using, and what are your impressions of them.

Comment: First step is always to create a raw copy with dd_rescue, before doing any other step. Especially, connecting them to a Windows system may cause additional damage. For rescuing data, you need disks that are larger than the original disks. Also, RAID is not a backup, which you have learned now. Even with RAID, you still need backup.

Comment: I googled this question. 

Most often, the following programs are recommended for data recovery from raid arrays: EaseUS RAID Data Recovery, Hetman RAID Recovery,  DiskInternals RAID Recovery, ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery, R-Studio, UFS Explorer.

Does anyone have experience using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried some of the programs listed above and R-Studio and Hetman RAID Recovery read my drives from the RAID array without any problems. They configured it correctly and displayed all the data.
[image: qnap raid recovery]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).